# Rendering templated HtmlHelper with MVC3/Razor

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have a HtmlHelper that renders a grid as a table, in MVC2 I would call it from the view using the following syntax...

```
<%=
    Html.MyLibrary().Grid<MyGridItem>()
        .Name("MyGrid")
        .Width("100%")
        .Render()
%>
```

Notice it uses templates. In MVC3 with Razor it won't compile, seemingly because the left angle bracket '<' is being confused for html. To get around this I can enclose it in curly braces...

```
@{Html.MyLibrary().Grid<MyGridItem>()
        .Name("MyGrid")
        .Width("100%")
        .Render();}
```

but now the problem is that the string returned from .Render() doesn't get put in the output stream!

Any help solving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Html.Raw() Method.

```
@Html.Raw(Html.MyLibrary().Grid<MyGridItem>()
        .Name("MyGrid")
        .Width("100%")
        .Render())
```

The @{...} server side block does not get rendered because it's simple server side code. Same if you wrote

```
@{ "renderedstring".ToString(); }
```